# Custom server-side GTM tagging and preview servers /healtzh endpoint show 200/OK but the debugginh/preview mode in GTM doesn't work

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

Pretty much the title.
I have tagging server here https://gtm.stastnamama.sk/healthz
and I have preview server here https://preview.gtm.stastnamama.sk/healthz
both shows OK but when I try to enter preview mode in GTM I get HTTP ERROR 500
Does anyone know what to look for that could cause the problem?
Thank you in advance for any help.

I double checked all the settings and configurations and everything seems to be right.